# Piece-wise quadratic function

Tags: functions, optimization, quadratics, machine-learning

How can I find a minimum of a piece-wise quadratic function? 
(**minorant of a set of quadratic functions**)

An example of this will be appreciated.

Comment: You  are asking two different things.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum of every piece is the smallest of the values at the endpoints and at the stationary point (if any). The global minimum is the smallest of all pieces.

Comment: thanks, could you please explain this by example. Suppose I have piece-wise quadratic functions then I want to find their minorant function.

Comment: @jeza: no idea what you call their "minorant function".

Comment: Just it is the minimum of piece-wise quadratic functions

Comment: @jeza: why do you call that a *function* ?

Comment: because I found this following statement in one of the paper I read "We exploited the fact that ﬁnding a minimum of a piece-wise quadratic function, or, in other words, a function which is the minorant of a set of quadratic functions, is not much more computationally costly as minimizing the standard quadratic error". which I do not understand?

Comment: @jeza: the searched minmum is the minimum minimorum of all the parabolas.

Comment: I do not really understand it. Could you please provide a very simple example of this.